# Store Reference of Variable in another variable

Tags: c#

I am writing a bit of code which needs to me to parse a special character separated string, and assign it to a set of variables. I am using following logic now.

```
        string Variable1, Variable2, Variable3, Variable4, Variable5, Variable6;
        string TestString = "One|Two|Three|Four|Five|Six";
        string[] Arr = TestString.Split('|');

        Variable1 = Arr[0];
        Variable2 = Arr[1];
        Variable3 = Arr[2];
        Variable4 = Arr[3];
        Variable5 = Arr[4];
        Variable6 = Arr[5];
```

This works fine, but I was wondering if I could have some sort of collection, wherein, I can specify the order of variables which will hold the sub string, and then assign it, rather than going through 'Variable1 = Arr[0]' kind of steps.

The idea or reasoning behind such a question is, there are cases when the variable list might be around 50-60s (variables aren't always named var1, they have meaningful name). In such a situation, chances of error is more, wherein, if I had a collection, say a Queue, and I could assign the order, it would be much easier to avoid errors.

Update: Basically, am looking to store reference of a variable in another variable.

Thanks
Anu

Comment: _"...specify the order of variables..."_ -- specify, how? Exactly? There are lots of alternatives to the code you posted. But if you want to be able to specify the order of the variables, won't that just look a lot like what you already have? In what way is the code you showed _not_ "specifying the order of the variables"? Off the top of my head, I can think of at least three approaches different from what you have above, but it's not clear at all what you're looking for here.

Comment: Hi Peter. I have this particular file, which is has sub parts defined and separated by special character. The subparts may run upto 60. So if i was to split and assign as in the code above, the code might be a long list of 'var1=arr[0]' steps.
I wanted to avoid that. Instead, what I thought was, I will create, say an Array, {variable1,variable2} , which contains references to the variables. Please note that this doesn't contain value, rather references to variables. And then I intend to call a function, where I pass the split string array, and this collection of reference variables.

Comment: OMG! Why you don't use a collection like an string array? You can add each value with a loop and read these with the same way. Also, you say : " (variables aren't always named var1, they have meaningful name)" If It won't have the same name like var1,var2,var3, you can use a Dictionary with a key and a value. How do you want to order your collection? You can use LINQ :D

Comment: Nop, in the particular scenario am in, I cannt use Dictionary. I need them as separate variables. I guess it is not possible to store reference to variables in another variable.

Comment: `string Variable1 = null, Variable2 = null, Variable3 = null, Variable4 = null, Variable5 = null, Variable6 = null; var setters = new Action<string>[] { v => Variable1 = v, v => Variable2 = v, v => Variable3 = v, v => Variable4 = v, v => Variable5 = v, v => Variable6 = v }; string TestString = "One|Two|Three|Four|Five|Six"; string[] Arr = TestString.Split('|'); for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) { setters[i](Arr[i]); }`

Comment: That what you describe is called a class. It can have many properties and you need to remember only one reference to access all those properties/values. Read http://www.filehelpers.net/example/QuickStart/ReadFileDelimited/

Comment: It's unclear to me exactly what you are doing, but you can get a **reference** to a Field/Property "by name" using **REFLECTION**.  Do a search and you'll find it...

Comment: _"I intend to call a function, where I pass the split string array, and this collection of reference variables"_ -- you failed to answer my question. C# does not, without `unsafe` code, allow for references to variables. But even if it did, how is having to name each variable individually when you create this hypothetical array in any way better than just writing a method takes an array of split values and which has a separate statement to assign each variable? Either way, you have to write the name of each variable.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using pointers in C#. I would not recommend it, and I believe C# forces you to put it in a unsafe block. But yes, with pointers it is possible to store reference t a variable into another variable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types

Answer (score 0):

It is still unclear what you want to achieve. If you still want to use individual variables or fields or properties, then you can improve slightly by doing this. The point is that now it is the order of the assignments that determines which value is assigned to which variable. No longer a need to use indexes.

```
string _testString = "One|Two|Three|Four|Five|Six";
string[] _strings;
int _index = 0;

string GetNextValue()
{
    return _strings[_index++];
}

void Main()
{
    _strings = _testString.Split('|');
    var First = GetNextValue();
    var Second = GetNextValue();
    var Third = GetNextValue();
    var Fourth = GetNextValue();
    var Fifth = GetNextValue();
    var Sixth = GetNextValue();
}
```